# How to display lat-lng points on map when open notification ?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-notifications

I am developing one application in that I want to show map when I open notification, I received notification successfully but when I open notification not open map with that lat long values.

GCMIntent Service class

```
 public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{

Context context;
public static int notify_no=0;

//System.currentTimeMillis();

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public static final String TAG = "GCM NOTIFICATION";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);


     if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

         if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
               // sendNotification(RegIdDTO.REG_ID,"Send error: " + extras.toString());
             sendNotification(this,msg);
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
               // sendNotification(RegIdDTO.REG_ID,"Deleted messages on server: " +
               //         extras.toString());
                sendNotification(this,msg);
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
               // sendNotification(RegIdDTO.REG_ID,msg);
                sendNotification(this,msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
     GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}


private static void sendNotification(Context context,String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("header")
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500).setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("Notification from Traffic")
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
            .setSound(alarmSound);
    String consumerid = null;
    Integer position = null;
           // write your click event here
       Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ShowMapActivity.class);

       resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
      // resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+when));


PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
        notify_no, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Show the max number of notifications here
if (notify_no < 9) {
    notify_no = notify_no + 1;
} else {
    notify_no = 0;
}
 nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
 NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 nNotifyMgr.notify(notify_no + 2, nBuilder.build());
}

}
```

ShowMap class

```
 public class ShowMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

     GoogleMap _googleMap;

    LatLng myPosition;
    LocationManager locationManger;


    TextView addressTextView,cTimeTextView;

        JSONObject json;
        GcmIntentService serv;
        Context mContext;

    Intent noticeIntent = getIntent();

    String lat;
    String lng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);

    //addressTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressId);
    //cTimeTextView   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ctimeId);

    String message = noticeIntent.getExtras().getString("message");

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(message);
        lat = json.getString("lat");

         Log.e("LLOONNGG", ""+lat);
        lng = json.getString("lng");

         Log.e("LLOONNGG", ""+lng);
        String adr = json.getString("address");
        addressTextView.setText(adr);


        String ctime = json.getString("ctime");
        cTimeTextView.setText(ctime);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    _googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap(); 

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean enableGPS = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enableWiFi= service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(!enableGPS || !enableWiFi){
        Toast.makeText(ShowMapActivity.this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    locationManger = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);


    if(_googleMap==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Map Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //locationManger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    _googleMap.clear();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) 
            getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayList");


    /*if(location!=null){
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double langitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latlang = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);
        //LatLngBounds curScreen =    
            _googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        //curScreen.contains(latlang);
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

             // Show only Current Location

        _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition)); 
        _googleMap.addMarker(new 
         MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));

    }*/

    if ( !lat.trim().equals("") && !lng.trim().equals("") ) {
        double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
        double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng.trim());

        LatLng dabaseLocations =new LatLng(Hlat, Hlong);

        Log.e("LLAATTAA", ""+Hlat);
        Log.e("LLOONNGG", ""+Hlong);


        // Show current location with database locations

          _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dabaseLocations)); 
         _googleMap.addMarker(new    
       MarkerOptions().position(dabaseLocations).title("start"));
          }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    serv=new GcmIntentService();
    //serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext());

}

 }
```

my Logcat

```
03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
```

Logcat

```
    ComponentInfo{com.technowellServices.traffic/com.technowellServices.traffic.ShowMapActivity}:   
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
        03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
         android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
        03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
         android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
        03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
       android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
      android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
      java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at j
    ava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
   Method)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
    com.technowellServices.traffic.ShowMapActivity.onCreate(ShowMapActivity.java:66)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
    03-06 13:03:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at 
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1692)
```

Comment: is your activity opening?

Comment: is your activity register in `manifest.xml`?

Comment: no not opining my activity

Comment: ya registered in manifest

Comment: i added exeption in logcat please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call this

```
 Intent noticeIntent = getIntent();
```

before onCreate() method.

You should put it **in** onCreate() method.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);
     Intent noticeIntent = getIntent();  
     // ...
 }
```

Change this from

```
  String message = noticeIntent.getExtras().getString("message");
```

to

```
 String message = noticeIntent.getStringExtras("message");
```

Comment: sry for the late response its coming map,but i want to go directly to my location without zoom out from map,.how it is possible please tell me

Comment: you can use CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

Comment: ya it worked only one time,from second notification onwards not shows directly

Comment: it is coming now but the marker just com and gone here my logcat error  time going backwards: prev 1392207807105446(ioctl) vs now 1392207806984404(ioctl), tid=19417   what happining?

Comment: the marker came but with in seconds it gone again,there is no marker in map

Comment: just for checking remove this one or comment it

Comment: i removed same thing happening

Comment: Ok just comment this _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dabaseLocations));  and chcek if will get success means need to solve by this.

Comment: yes i totally mistake it not a problem from that ,i used map.clear() it is happening from this, thanks allot you spent a valuable time for me

Answer (score 1):

You should create `noticeIntent` inside `onCreate(....)` in your `ShowMapActivity` like

```
Intent noticeIntent = getIntent();
String message = noticeIntent.getStringExtras("message");
```